# Как работает переменная "Count"

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int t,count;

for(t=0;t<10;t++)
{
    count = 1;
    for(; ;) {
        cout << count << " ";
        count++;
        if (count == 10)
            break;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    }
return 0;
}
```

Эта программа выводит числа от 1 до 9| 9 раз.И я не понимаю,мы даже как следует не присоединили переменную "Count" к циклу for.Как вообще оно повторяется 8 раз подряд?Можете объяснить

Comment: А вот это видите? `count++`?

Comment: Я это вижу,но не понимаю,почему count выводит 8 раз от 1 до 9| Я понимаю,Что там стоит Break,но как это вообще возможно?В книжке не объяснено

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот этот внутренний  цикл

```
1    count = 1;
2    for(; ;) {
3        cout << count << " ";
4        count++;
5        if (count == 10)
6            break;
7    }
```

по сути то же, что и

```
for(count = 1; count < 10; count++)
{
    cout << count << " ";
}
```

Просто инициализация вынесена за цикл, а проверка условия и инкремент - в тело цикла...

**Update**

Я пронумеровал строки. Пошли... Итак, 1 - понятно, 2 - вошли в цикл с `count` равной 1, 3 - вывели ее (1), 4 - увеличили. 5 - проверка - сейчас `count` равна 2, идем дальше к строке 2.

2 - вошли в цикл с `count` равной 2, 3 - вывели ее (2), 4 - увеличили. 5 - проверка - сейчас `count` равна 3, идем дальше к строке 2.

...

2 - вошли в цикл с `count` равной 9, 3 - вывели ее (9), 4 - увеличили. 5 - проверка - сейчас `count` равна 10, всё, `break`, т.е. выход из цикла.

Так понятно?

Comment: Спасибо,всегда помогаете в трудный момент!

Comment: Да,еще раз спасибо за объяснение!

Comment: Я так понимаю,что переменная "t" повторяет бесконечный цикл for с переменной "count" 9 раз,да?

Comment: А вот можно вас попросить об одном одолжении?Можете дать свои социальные сети,чтобы я мог спросить,если вам не трудно.Просто может быть вы тратите много времени на ответ здесь,а например в социальных сетях быстрее.

Comment: Простите, но нет...

Comment: Хорошо,но все равно спасибо!!